# Can I Charge With An MCP73831?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

Sometimes I need to take my laptop places and, it doesn't have the greatest battery life, sometimes maybe it only lasts 10 minutes.

So after researching a bit I decided I wanted to build a li-ion S3P5 battery pack like this: [image: S35P Battery Pack]

with an added on inverter for ac power. I was planning on using this [BMS](https://www.ebay.ca/i/273812152638?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=706-89093-2056-0&mkcid=2&itemid=273812152638&targetid=536716739722&device=c&adtype=pla&googleloc=9001084&poi=&campaignid=1669215026&adgroupid=63013117165&rlsatarget=pla-536716739722&abcId=1140226&merchantid=10252592&gclid=Cj0KCQjw3uboBRDCARIsAO2XcYCyNTm2XLRxMNXyEi0jPeDmrz5lSms51KQDf4hRUNj2nc64hqhiiJEaAlHVEALw_wcB), I was wondering if I could charge it with an MCP73831 based battery charger (Yes, I do know that it is meant for single cell charging but i'm curious) since the BMS would take care of the balancing.

Comment: You really need a new laptop battery. (Amazon) but to answer your question... NO Way only 1 cell as cuttoff is defined for 5%CC for 1 cell CC, CV.    But you can use chip with V/3 to control external regulator using 0.1% resistor ratio and charger with status logic to control Cutoff but not CC/CV

Comment: *I was wondering if I could charge it with an MCP73831 based battery charger* In principle that would be possible using 3 separate and isolated power supplies (so you need 3 mains sockets!). **However** "being possible" doesn't mean "good idea". The MCP73831 charges with only up to 0.5 A so it might take **20 hours or more** to charge the cells. Building your own battery pack will cost you as much as just getting a new battery, the price is in the cells. If you pay much less, you are buying **crappy** cells. That's wasted money.

Comment: If the MCP73831 is built for one cell, then odds won't charge more than one cell because it would hit a voltage or current limit depending on the cell configuration.

Comment: I was suggesting use the chip to regulate a FET with Feedback using an Opamp and Chip output and Status logic for cutoff. Thus scaling 12.6V to 4.2V. To compare Vout to Vbat of 5P3S but current sensing needs more work so charger must be  current limited somehow.  But this takes effort better spent going shopping